# inheritance and event handlers c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, inheritance, event-handling

Ok guys I'm totally new to stackoverflow, let me know if I stuff something up.

I am making a class library for sockets and then using the class library to make a server. The issue I've run into is this:

In the class library I have a class called `sockets` that has event handlers (you know like connection made, closed so on) and in the server I'm making, I have a class named `player` which inherits from `sockets`.

The problem pretty much comes down to this.
I use the `OnConnectionMade` event handler to create my `player`, but because I cant do `instanceOfInheritedClass = intanceOfBaseClass`, even when I make use of use of the event handlers, the event handlers wont trigger because `instanceOfInheritedClass` isn't pointing to `intanceOfBaseClass` event, if I pass through the parameters.

```
void hostManager_OnConnectionMade(object source, ConnectionArgs e)
{
    Player socket = new Player(e.GetSocket());
    socket.OnDataRecivedPostConvert += Socket_OnDataRecivedPostConvertLogin;
}

public Player(DDSocket socket)
{
    this.Host = socket.Host;
    this.Socket = socket.Socket;
    //this.OnConnectionClosed += socket.OnConnectionClosed;
    //this.OnDataRecivedPostConvert += socket.OnDataRecivedPostConvert;
    //this.OnDataRecivedPostConvertHost += socket.OnDataRecivedPostConvertHost;
}
```

One of the solutions I came up with was that instead of inheriting, I can just make it a `intanceOfBaseClass` parameter in the `player` class. But that will prevent me from making proper use of object `source` from my event handlers which will mean I'll need to use linq or something to find the `player` from the `socket` or something like that.

The other thing I thought about doing was somehow passing the event handlers over, which you can see I tried, but don't know how to do.

Now after hours of looking it up I'm stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated
and any answer that solves this issue is fine. I'm not picky with how its solved.

Answer (score 0):

Despite that your `Player` class is inherited from `DDSocket`, but in this scenario, it acts as the wrapper class  of `DBSocket`, so there is one hack to achieve that, I think you have to do some further steps:

```
class DDSocket
{
    public event Action OnConnectionClosed;
    public void Raise()
    {
        if (OnConnectionClosed != null)
        {
            OnConnectionClosed();
        }
    }
}



class Player :DDSocket
{
    // make new event look as the same base class
    public new event Action OnConnectionClosed;
    public Player(DDSocket socket)
    {
        socket.OnConnectionClosed += Socket_OnConnectionClosed;
    }

    private void Socket_OnConnectionClosed()
    {
       if (OnConnectionClosed != null)
        {
            OnConnectionClosed();
        }
    }
}

// test those 2 classes
static void Main()
    {           
        DDSocket d = new DDSocket();

        Player pl = new Player(d);
          pl.OnConnectionClosed += () => MessageBox.Show("test");
        d.Raise();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering tbh I got really busy with more important stuff after I posted this so I haven't even had a chance to look into it, thanks a lot and I'll get back to this one day.